# Java generics: How to specify exact method signature

Tags: java, generics

I have a class with various constructors:

```
public class SomeClass {

    public SomeClass(Object obj) {
        Log.d("x", "SomeClass(Object)");
    }

    public SomeClass(Integer num) {
        Log.d("x", "SomeClass(Integer)");
    }

    public SomeClass(String str) {
        Log.d("x", "SomeClass(String)");
    }

    public <K, V> SomeClass(Map<K, V> map) {
        Log.d("x", "SomeClass(List)");
        for (K key : map.keySet()) {
            new SomeClass(key);
            new SomeClass(map.get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

...and some code which uses it in following way:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key", 100);
new SomeClass(map);
```

In the result I have such output:

```
"SomeClass(List)"
"SomeClass(Object)"
"SomeClass(Object)"
```

instead of required

```
"SomeClass(List)"
"SomeClass(String)"
"SomeClass(Integer)"
```

I suppose that because of Java Type Erasure the nested calls of SomeClass constructors falls to the most general one.

**The Question:** any ideas how to overcome this Java behavior and force it to call constructor with required parameter type? (Static wrappers and Fabric pattern is not accepted here)

Comment: Are you only using this class with a `Map<String, Integer>` or also maps with other types?

Comment: Besides checking the type of the key and value with instanceof, I don't see any *accepted* way. I think the design should be changed, but you seem to be rejecting that option, so... For example, I don't understand the point of making the constructor parameterized. You could just use Map<?, ?>.

Comment: Java uses the static type to resolve the method, in case of generics it is the erasure so here `Object`. Besides manually casting to the intended type or using reflection your options with constructors are limited. You could change the constructor signature to `SomeClass(Map<String,Integer> map)`. But the more general solution is to fix your design.

Comment: It can be any type of key/value pair. In my case this class contains much more constructors, not only mentioned above.

Comment: This is basically template specialization, which is not possible, because generics are not templates.

Comment: **JB Nizet**, you are right, parameterized constructor is not required in case of the Map. It's just an attempt to resolve the problem. Could you please clarify how "instanceof" can help in this situation?

Comment: He means something like this:  `if (key instanceof String) { new SomeClass((String) key); } else { ...`

Comment: Yes, it will work. But size of the code to handle all the supported types is terrible((

Comment: How about reflection? Is there any compact solution?

Answer (score 2):

Overload is done at compile time and therefore uses the static type of a variable rather than the runtime type. This is nothing to do with generics.

Consider the code:

```
Object value = "value";
SomeClass something = new SomeClass(value);
```

Then the `SomeClass(Object)` overload is used.

You could use `instanceof`, but that's usually a good indication that there is something wrong in the design. Almost certainly you want the `Map` to have a relevant type. At the moment you could write the last constructor as:

```
public SomeClass(Map<?, ?> map) {
```

(BTW, generic constructors are really obscure.)

Comment: As far as I understand, you suggest to insert big {if-elseif-elseif-...-else} block with "instanceof" condition in general SomeClass(Object value) constructor. I had such solution before, it works as expected. Now I'm trying to find any better solution and avoid that ugly code...

Comment: @SergeyKrivenkov The problem isn't that `instanceof` is ugly, but that the design relies upon identifying runtime types.